# Auto generation of chords based on string tuning

Tags: music

I'm looking for software that can auto generate chords for obscure string instruments or weird tunings.

Let's give a scenario:

- I have purchased a rare South American string instrument.
- I input the number of strings and their individual tuning (maybe some are double string with different tuning, maybe some are single string or double string in same tuning). *this one is vital. I know there is software that does the next for a specific instrument, but I am looking for something that has this functionality here*
- I ask for a specific chord (might be very complex or very simple)
- It outputs the possible ways to play that chord.

I have my doubts if such a piece of software exists, considering that you have to take into account the limitations of the human hand (maybe as well as commodity).

I prefer (not required; though) that the software is:

- Compatible with Windows, Linux, or Android
- Gratis

Comment: Any OS preferred? Does it have to be free?

Comment: Preferably Windows/Linux/Android (which is what I own). Free would be nice, but I would be willing to pay.

Answer (score 1):

it's not exactly what you're looking for, but Chord.Rocks will do most of what you're asking. It's a website so it's free and will work on any web browser of device. it can do chord and scale lookups and reverse chord and scale lookups.

http://chord.rocks/

It includes several music instruments, mostly stringed. You can enter any custom tuning. so if your rare south american string instrument has 6 strings, you can select "guitar", enter the tuning, and the chords and scales will be the same. You can do this for instruments with 4 (ukulele), 5 (5 string bass), 6 (guitar), or 7 (7 string guitar) string instruments.

It won't fill all of your requirements since it can't do more than 7 strings or work with double stringed instruments where the strings are tuned differently. but it might be as close as you can get (especially for free).

Comment: What is your affiliation with that website? Please disclose.